# Troubleshooting error 0xc000000e on Windows boot with Bitlocker full drive encryption

Tags: multi-boot, mbr, bitlocker, bcd, bootmgr

**Note:** I had originally thought that the BCD was the problem, which turned out to be wrong.

---

I originally had my laptop set up as follows:

- A 300 GB partition with OS X 10.10 and native full-drive encryption (FileVault).
- A 200 GB partition with Windows 10 and native full-drive encryption (BitLocker).
- A rEFInd boot manager installed on the ESP in `/EFI/boot`.
- A Microsoft boot manager installed on the ESP in `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot`.

Two days ago, I shrinked the OS X partition to 200GB and added a 100GB partition in between, on which I installed Ubuntu.
Ever since then, I have been unable to boot Windows.
When entering the Windows boot manager, I'm still prompted for the password, but after that, I get a screen saying

> Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
>
> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Error code: 0xc000000e

I then inserted my Windows 10 installation drive, and went to inspect the partition from the command line (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>).
But `diskpart` proved unable to mount the partition, because it apparently operates on the MBR.
(I made sure I booted the installation drive in EFI mode (via a manual boot stanza in rEFInd), and so I expected `diskpart` to operate on the GPT, but oh well...)

The MBR originally container four partitions:

- ESP
- Macintosh HD
- Recovery HD
- BOOTCAMP

The GPT additionally contained a BitLocker recovery partition after BOOTCAMP.
It turned out that adding the Linux partition had changed pushed BOOTCAMP out of the list, and made "Linux HD" the fourth partition.
I simply adjusted the MBR to have the last entry point to BOOTCAMP again, thus "skipping" the Linux partition.

After that, I was still able to boot OS X and Ubuntu, and I was now also able to mount the windows partition from `diskpart`.
And I managed to unlock the partition with

```
manage-bde -unlock W: -Password
```

proving that 1) I didn't mess up the MBR, and 2) the partition was still intact.

In light of this, I'm pretty sure that the problem lies in the BCR.
For reasons still unclear to me I am unable to mount the ESP from the installation drive - trying to assign a drive letter to the first partition of disk 0 tells me that "There is no volume specified", but `list volume` only lists everything that's already mounted.
`bootrec /rebuildbcd` also fails horribly, removing the BCD file **from the installation drive**.
However, I am able to simply copy the BCD to the installation drive, and use `bcdedit` on it.

`bcedit /store BCD` prints:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  unknown
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {cc3e7046-4857-11e5-a015-f353893f9a4c}
displayorder            {default}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  unknown
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoveryenabled         No
custom:16000060         Yes
custom:17000077         352321653
osdevice                unknown
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {cc3e7046-4857-11e5-a015-f353893f9a4c}
nx                      OptIn
custom:250000c2         1
```

Now these `unknown` didn't look so good to me, so I changed them to `partition=W:` using

```
bcdedit /store BCD /set {default} device partition=W:
bcdedit /store BCD /set {default} osdevice partition=W:
```

And I verified the result:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  unknown
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {cc3e7046-4857-11e5-a015-f353893f9a4c}
displayorder            {default}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=W:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoveryenabled         No
custom:16000060         Yes
custom:17000077         352321653
osdevice                partition=W:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {cc3e7046-4857-11e5-a015-f353893f9a4c}
nx                      OptIn
custom:250000c2         1
```

But after pushing that BCD file back onto my ESP, the Windows boot manager doesn't even prompt me for a password anymore, but instead immediately display me a different error, saying

> Your PC/Device needs to be repaired.
>
> The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.
>
> File: \Windows\system32\winload.efi
>   Error code: 0xc0000225

I tried setting `device` and `osdevice` before and after decrypting the `W:` drive, with the same result.
Setting `device` for `{bootmgr}` also made no difference.
Now, I'm pretty sure that this was a step back, because it doesn't even ask for my password anymore.

I also noticed that even running `bcdedit /store BCD` made quite a lot of changes to the file, given the fact that there were no data changes.
Among other things, the file would apparently contain its own path, being `Volume1\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD` for the original BCD file, and `??\C:\BCD` for my modified file.
I was at first worried that this would in some way "impurify" the file, but I ran a test, changing `description` of `{default}` to `Windows 42`, which, again, caused quite a lot of changes in the file, but the Windows boot manager still asked me for a password when using that file, so neither does a custom file location "impurify" the file, nor is the `bcdedit` I'm using broken.

Now, finally my question:

**How can I repair my BCD?

Or if that's not the issue, then what is, and how can I fix it?**

---

Additional info:

`diskutil list`

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         200.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.1 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data                         99.0 GB    disk0s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data                         199.7 GB   disk0s5
   6: DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC               363.9 MB   disk0s6
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *200.0 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 4A45027B-2703-4C7D-816E-3419DE0F0F61
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

`sudo gpt show -l /dev/disk0`

```
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - "EFI System Partition"
     409640  391334208      2  GPT part - "Customer"
  391743848    1269760      3  GPT part - "Recovery HD"
  393013608       1688         
  393015296  193355776      4  GPT part - "Linux HD"
  586371072       2048         
  586373120  390019148      5  GPT part - "BOOTCAMP"
  976392268       1972         
  976394240     710656      6  GPT part - ""
  977104896        131         
  977105027         32         Sec GPT table
  977105059          1         Sec GPT header
```

`sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 60821/255/63 [977105060 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   2 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
*2: DA 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  391334208] <Unknown ID>
 3: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 391743848 -    1269760] HFS+        
 4: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 586373120 -  390019148] HPFS/QNX/AUX
```

The Windows boot manager with the original BCD:

[image: asking for password]

The Windows boot manager with the original BCD after entering my password:

[image: error 0xc000000e]

The Windows boot manager with a modified BCD:

[image: error 0xc0000225]

#### Update 1:

I tried marking BOOTCAMP as "bootable" in the MBR, with no change at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The BCD was actually fine, it was the MBR that was causing all the trouble.

I had already decrypted my drive<sup>[1]</sup> and was attempting to reinstall Windows, but when selecting the drive gave me a popup, saying something like "this hard drive uses MBR, but EFI-based systems can only be installed on GPT drives".
So apparently, on Windows, MBR takes precedence over GPT.

I went ahead and replaced my MBR with a "protective" one, using

```
sudo gdisk /dev/disk0   # On Linux, use /dev/sda
r                       # Recovery/transformation
x                       # Expert mode
n                       # New protective MBR
w                       # Write changes to disk
y                       # Yes (confirm)
```

(On Linux, `gdisk` should be installed by default (otherwise try `sudo apt-get install gdisk`), on Mac you can get it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/).)

This finally solved my problem.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> It seems that isn't actually necessary, but for the record: Assuming your encrypted drive is labelled `W:`, first unlock it from the install drive command line, then run `manage-bde -off W:`, check the progress every now and then with `manage-bde -status W:`, and reboot once encryption hits 0%.

Comment: You really saved me today! :) I honestly wish I could give you more points!!
Just one minor thing (mostly to give this comment a reason to exist), you *could* be even more explicit that the fix involves *only* the `gdisk` thing and that there's no need to decrypt your BitLocker-partition, even if it was how you found the solution. It did confuse me a little. Anyway, I have nothing but gratitude for posting this, phew, Thank you so very much!!

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer. And you're welcome, man. :) I don't wish it upon anyone to have to figure this out for themselves.